# Word 2013: Get the page number for the previous page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, page-numbers, field-codes

I'm trying to accomplish something very simple in Word 2013, but the feature does not seem to be available, nor can I work it out with field codes.

I simply want to include, on multiple pages, "continued from page *n*".

In terms of field codes, I have tried this:

```
{ = PAGE - 1 \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

It just tells me that `PAGE` is not a defined bookmark.

Is there any way that this can be done?

#### Edit:

Per documentation I found somewhere, I also tried this - but with no luck:

```
{ = { PAGE } - 1 }
```

This just threw `Syntax Error, {` back, which leads me to assume that it's incompatible with newer versions of Word.

Comment: The more I search, it seems that this simply cannot be done...

Comment: I have to ask, why put "continues form pg. X" on the NEXT page referring to the previous?  Doesn't reading in general assume that the previous page is where you're coming from? Or is the `-1` just an example? Why not use bookmarks and [PAGEREFs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/field-codes-pageref-field-HA102017459.aspx) instead?

Comment: I see where you're coming from, and I do agree with you, but it is something my client wants. They've created this newsletter in newspaper style. But you are quite right - I don't particularly like the idea either... Nonetheless, it seems strange that the attempts I've made don't work.

Comment: I edited my comment while you were typing yours -- ie: PageRefs? :)

Comment: Not 100% sure how those work... Are those static references?

Comment: Nope, but if the pages move around to have to "refresh" the fields manually (similar to a Table of Contents).  I did mange to get it working as you expected though.. I'll throw that up as an answer.

Comment: But anyways, I'm opting out of even going any further. I'd rather just transform the way they send out these newsletters, and welcome them into the 21st century.

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean. No, that would never work for them. But, add it as an answer anyway. Others may find it helpful.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but as an alternative, have you tried MS's Publisher?  I seem to recall that you could add things in like 'continued from...' and it was somewhat programmatic.  I used it to create some news letters and actually liked it. Found it to be fairly useful.

Comment: I think I recall that too... I'll have a chat with them to see what they'd prefer: Publisher, or MailChimp-style newsletters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ ={ PAGE }-1 }` will work, but it all depends on how you input it (or else you get a Syntax error).

The trick is to add the field codes using Ctrl+F9 to perform an actual "add field code" instead of just typing braces in.

- Hit Ctrl+F9 to add a field code.
- In that type `=`.
- Then hit Ctrl+F9 again to add another field code.
- Type in `PAGE`.
- Arrow over, past the first closing brace.
- Enter `-1`.
- Click out of the field(s) and right-click -> Toggle Field Codes.
- It should now display the current page # - 1.

Alternatively, and I think perhaps more appropriately (if sticking with Word), you should look into using Bookmarks and the "PageRef" code instead.

More info on that from MS: [Field codes: PageRef field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/field-codes-pageref-field-HA102017459.aspx)

> The PageRef field inserts the page number of a bookmark for a cross-reference. To cross-reference items in a document, use the Cross-reference command (Insert tab, Links group).

Comment: Magical! Didn't know it had to be done like that. :D Missed out on the second Ctrl+F9.

Comment: Yeah, usually it's smart enough to figure out when you type the braces in manually, but I think once they start getting nested, it has trouble tracking if they're codes, or just braces in the text.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but what happens to Page 1. Does it become Page 0 with the code?

Comment: @SunWKim Well, you could just try it.  ;)  But yeah it shows 0 on page 1 (1-1=0).

Comment: Indeed, it would. But who would put the field on the first page anyway?

Comment: @MikeAnthony Dunno man, your client might want that TOO. ;)  "...Continued from page 0". :)

Comment: If someone put the code in the header or footer, some kind of logic to exclude the first page or last page may have been helpful. That's where I was going with that question...

Comment: @SunWKim, yes for sure, nothing that can't be solved without further nesting of IF fields :)

Comment: @techie: Haha, I wouldn't be surprised ;) Sun: You just use the "different on first page" option... It's in the ribbon. Though Adam is quite right indeed. :)